# date culture of dateTime.FromOaDate()

Tags: c#, datetime

does DateTime.FromOaDate() always return the date in the en_US culture (mm/dd/yyyy)?

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime` values don't *have* a culture any more than `Int32` values do. The idea of a culture only gets applied when you start formatting or parsing the value.

Comment: Jon Skeet: So if I write DateTime.FromOaDate(doubleValue).ToString(), then it will take the current culture and return accordingly, right ?

Comment: @Marshal: Yes (assuming you actually pass an argument to `FromOaDate` of course).

Comment: Jon Skeet: Your eyes are compiler. Thanks.